# Capturing Console python prints in C# in real time

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to create a python process from C# and get the prints from the python script.

This is what I have in my C# code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class CreateProcess
    {
        public String PythonPath { get; set; }
        public String FilePath { get; set; }
        public String Arguments { get; set; }
        public Process process;

        public void run_cmd()
        {

            this.process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = this.PythonPath,
                Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FilePath, this.Arguments),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            };

            this.process.StartInfo = start;
            this.process.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
            this.process.Start();
            this.process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            //this.process.WaitForExit();
        }

        void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Data);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateProcess test = new CreateProcess();
            test.PythonPath = "mypathtopython.exe";
            test.FilePath = "pythonfilename";
            test.Arguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3";
            test.run_cmd();
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the WaitForExit() method, I get this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

When I keep it, it works, but the output prints to my console when the python process stops running (which is to be expected). I want it though to happen in real time..any idea where I'm doing it wrong?

This might be a problem in python and not in C# but I'm not sure how to fix it. This is my python testing script:

```
import time
import os
import sys

print("First example")
time.sleep(10)
print("Arguments given:",sys.argv)
```

I've also tried using sys.stdout.flush() but to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with buffering of IO,
in python after each print you should flush the buffer
**sys.stdout.flush()**